# What is the difference between the ET_Client class in the API an the ExacttargetSoapClient?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

Both seem to have the ability to do unsubscribes, adds, retrieves, deletes... pretty much anything I can think of. But the ExacttargetSoapClient class requires a username and password whereas the ET_Client seems to hook up to an app using a Secret and such. So what does one do that the other doesn't? And why would you choose to use one over the other?

Update: The application itself must be written in php.

Comment: Sorry - I am assuming this is for php. Maybe it's not? There really isn't enough detail in your question to know.

Comment: Yes. I update the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference in the client library being used.

`ExacttargetSoapClient` is a pure PHP library, and mostly outdated.

`ET_Client` is the Fuel Client Library (currently labeled SDK), and it utilizes the newer app model and authentication flow using `clientId` and `clientSecret`.  It stream lines much of the older library with better methods.

The Fuel Client library also abstracts our SOAP and REST APIs. Our SOAP API is our oldest and most comprehensive API, but its functionality is limited to the ExactTarget email application, and, like all SOAP APIs, it is fairly heavyweight. Our REST API is newer and less comprehensive, but it exposes a broader set of Marketing Cloud capabilities and is much more lightweight and easy to use (and is getting more comprehensive with every release).

You can get the PHP Client Library (SDK) here - https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP/tree/Dot9/

Comment: Interesting. So for the purposes of development, even if you're writing in PHP, the recommendation is that one works with the ET_Client/Fuel Client Library due to it's ease of use?

Comment: Completely. The docs need updated.